# Mistake in the Algorithm Design Manual?

Tags: algorithms

Look at this excerpt from the Algorithm Design Manual by Skiena, 2nd Edition:

[image]

"The sum of the first $n$ **even** integers"? Surely, the two given versions of the sum given do not include only even numbers. Is this a mistake on the author's part, or am I missing something?

Comment: Looks to me like "even" doesn't belong there.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that "even" is referred to $n$ (otherwise he would not be able to divide it by $2$, which he does). It's badly written anyway.

Comment: What is actually meant is that the two sums together give $n(n+1)$ which is actually even for all $n$, but this should have been explicitely mentioned. Much easier would be mentioning $$2+4+6+\cdots 2n=2(1+2+3+\cdots +n)=2\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}=n(n+1)$$ But apparently , the pairing mehod was intented to be shown.

Comment: I disagree with Leo and Peter and agree with Gerry. Clearly, "even" (incorrectly) refers to $i$. "The first $n$ even integers". Remove even and everything makes sense.

Comment: The statemment is not false (since it is only said "can be seen"), but I agree that mentioning the pairing idea , but then not mentioning that we must use the sum of the sums, is misleading.

Comment: @Sandi It is possible, but unlikely that the author uses the word "even" without actually meaning the even numbers. It also makes sense, if we say that the sum of the first $n$ even numbers is the sum of the two sums (having the same value) , so I tend to believe it was meant this way.

Comment: I see what you mean now. But wow, what a confusing way to type it.

Comment: @Sandi I agree!

Comment: @Sandi But to be fair, in articles usually sums are used rather than expressions like $1+2+3+\cdots+n$, Instead of the second sum, he should just have mentioned that the sum can be written in reverse order ($n+\cdots+3+2+1$) and that , if we sum them up get $n(n+1)$, which is also equal to the sum of the first even numbers. This would have been enlightening!

Answer (score -1):

Expanding those 3 equation makes the author's statement true, i.e:

$ 1+2+3+...+n=\frac{n(i+(n-i+1))}{2}=\frac{(ni+n^2-ni+n)}{2}=\frac{n^2+n}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=2+4+6+...+2n$

The confusing part could be the 2nd one though:

$ \sum_{i=1}^{n/2}(i+(n-1+1)) = 1/2(i+(n-i+1) \underbrace{...}_{n} i+(n-i+1) ) =  \frac{n(i+(n-i+1))}{2}$